# Yet another file renaming issue in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I've got a file with a unique substring in the file name. Therefore I'm matching it with a regex. For example, lets say that the file name is `someFile.asdf1234.txt`.

```
$fileNameRegex = [regex] 'someFile\.(.*).txt'
$fileName = Get-ChildItem C:\test | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match $fileNameRegex}
#         $fileName = 'someFile.asdf1234.txt'
#         so far this works.
```

What I'm having a hard time doing is use this info to rename the file

```
$arbitraryString = "random9753"
# the final file name needs to be "someFile.random9753.txt"
```

How do I reuse the same regex to rename the substring portion of the file name with the new `$arbitrartyString`?

*note: I don't mind changing the regex to meet the needs (possibly using groups), but I need to only have a single regex.*

Comment: I'm not following where you're having a problem...with the regex or the file rename?

Comment: I tried to clarify in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$fileNameRegex = [regex] '(someFile\.).*(\.txt)'
$fileName = 'someFile.asdf1234.txt'
$arbitraryString = "random9753"

$fileName -match $fileNameRegex > $nul
"$($matches[1])$arbitraryString$($matches[2])"

someFile.random9753.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to pull apart the file name into substrings and then concatenate them together.

```
$filename = "someFile.asdf1234.txt"
$arbitraryString = "random9753"


$newfilename = $filename.substring(0,$filename.IndexOf("."))
$newfilename += '.' + $arbitraryString + '.'
$newfilename += $filename.Substring($filename.Length -3)

Write-Host $newfilename
```